# How to password lock the terminal

Tags: command-line

How is it possible that I can password lock my terminal. I do not want anybody but me in the terminal. I want it so like when I start up the terminal, it will ask for a password, and if the password is incorrect, it will exit out, or maybe ask again. What are my possible ways I can do this?

Comment: Have you looked at `xscreensaver`?

Comment: @John1024 how is that supposed to help me?

Comment: It will password lock the monitor. If you are not running a GUI or you have other specific requirements that it doesn't meet, please clarify.

Comment: @user68186 the software, terminal. I want it so only i can access the terminal. I don't have multiple accounts, so what i mean is i wasn't a passcode lock on my terminal program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Right click on the terminal window and select Profiles -> Profile Preferences

2) Go to Title and Command tab

3) Check "Run a custom command" and in the Custom Command field, add `su yourusername`

4) Open a new window to check if this works

[image]

**Suggestions:**

- Some users run into a problem with `su` command, mainly this error `su initgroups: Operation not permitted` . In such case , use `sudo su yourusername`. If you do that make sure that you add line `Defaults    timestamp_timeout=7` in `/etc/sudoers` file so that after 7 minutes if someone wants to run something with root privileges , the won't be able to, because sudo has timed out. And it's a good security practice in general

Answer (score 0):

Lock your desktop if you're stepping away from your computer. Winkey (or meta key) + L will lock your screen. As long as you've set a password on your account, nobody else will be able to access it.